# How can I set my bootloader to load my primary (C:) partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, partitioning, bootloader

I created 4 partitions and want to use them to have seperate Windows XP, Windows 7, (possibly) Windows Vista installations, and "WinDummy" (to test applications in Vista, XP or another OS). I used Norton Ghost to install an OS to the drive in about 3 minutes.

My problem is that I installed the spare first on the 4th partition, then Windows 7 on the second. I tried to set the bootloader (with easybcd) to use the first partition - but it doesn't want to. Heres my debug screen on easybcd

As you can see, the device is set to H and i cant figure out how to change it. I can make my bootloader use Windows 7 first, but I can't make it use my C: install of XP instead of my spare H:.

How would I fix this?

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=H:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {bc2d8409-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
resumeobject            {bc2d8405-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
displayorder            {bc2d8409-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
                        {bc2d8406-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
                        {bc2d8404-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
                        {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 3

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {bc2d8409-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \NTLDR
description             Windows XP

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {bc2d8406-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {bc2d8407-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {bc2d8405-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
nx                      OptIn

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {bc2d8404-8640-11de-aa7e-a477d86453c4}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Blank
osdevice                partition=E:
systemroot              \Windows

Windows Legacy OS Loader
------------------------
identifier              {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c}
device                  partition=H:
path                    \ntldr
description             Windows XP Spare
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another boot entry of type Windows XP to your boot list using drive C. Make sure to name it so that you can recognize it.

This way you should be able to get the item to show up in the list and settable as default.

(I hope i'm understanding your question properly!)

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that. If you mean add it with easyBCD then i have. It is listed above as "Real-mode Boot Sector". In easybcd it looks like any other partition entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the 1st(XP) bootloader.  You are on the right track by using the Windows 7 bootloader (H). Just have it point to the XP partition. The order of the bootloaders isn't important.  More important is that the first bootloader is aware of all the other bootloaders and thus has the correct menu entries.